# Q: Linux kernel source - vt driver - ctrl-alt-fx commands

Tags: linux-kernel, keyboard-shortcuts

I'am looking for source file which manages tty switches. I think that it is in tty drivers, but i don't find it.

anybody knows where to look for ?

thank you
Gil

Comment: [set_console](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=set_console)

Comment: thank you, I would like to understand how linux manages shortcut keys to switch between tty. I think that set_console would be a good entry point to look for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I thank CL for his help gave me an entry point to look for keyboard shortcut management.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcuts are managed into 'drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c' file. 
'k_handler' function array is used to associate a process to a key sequence. Keys and sequences are detected into 'kbd_keycode' function.